# Unique value with Xquery and SoapUI

Tags: xquery, soapui

First of all, Sorry if I do mistake in my question. I'm french and not the best in english.
I have a problem with a Xquery Match in Soapui.
There is an exemple of a Soapui response:

```
<ns0:Group>
     <ns0:Personne>
        <ns0:idPersonne>111</ns0:idPersonne>
     </ns0:Personne>
     <ns0:Personne>
        <ns0:idPersonne>222</ns0:idPersonne>
     </ns0:Personne>
     <ns0:Personne>
        <ns0:idPersonne>333</ns0:idPersonne>
     </ns0:Personne>
</ns0:Group>
```

I need to check if the Id of a personne is unique or not.
If "111" appears only once, it returns "true"
If not, it returns "false".
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

```
count(distinct-values(//ns0:idPersonne)) eq 1
```

I am not that familiar with Soap UI though, so if you have trouble with namespaces you might also like to try instead:

```
count(distinct-values(//*:idPersonne)) eq 1
```

Comment: It was not exactly what I expected, but your answer help me to solve my problem (thanks to you).
`code` count(distinct-values(//ns0:idPersonne))=count(//ns0:idPersonne)
At left, we have all of distinct Personnes and at right, we have all Personnes. If there is no equality, it's because there are at least two same idPersonne

Comment: Okay sure, but that is not what you asked for in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that, maybe I did not express myself well. (It's already complicate in french, imagine in english for me ...)